# ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(); not working

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have created an app in iOS that uses Parse to store data and also uses Parse Push for messaging between users. I am now converting the app to Android and trying to use the same Parse backend for both.  I am successfully uploading/downloading data and I can even send a message from an Android user to a iOS user, but I can't get my Android device to receive messages. The underlining problem seems to be that I can't get the installation to work.  I am calling this block of code from my onCreate function:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, "id1", "id2");
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
   @Override
   public void done(ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
         Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
      } else {
         Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
      }
   }
});
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

After calling this code I check for a new installation in the database, but nothing ever shows up. It seems as though `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();` is not doing anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: put a callback inside the saveInBackground and check that you are not getting an error called "object not found for update"

Comment: Thanks, I did the callback and I am getting an error: "object not found for update". Do you know why I am getting this?

Comment: the object associated with the installation on the given device does not have a row in the parse installation table, this is why you are getting the error, there are 2 possible solutions to this problem : 1. uninstalling the app, and reinstalling it (which is an unacceptable solution), or 2. manually clearing the app parse cache. see the answer for how to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the object associated with the installation on the given device does not have a row in the parse installation table, this is why you are getting the error, there are 2 possible solutions to this problem :

- uninstalling the app, and reinstalling it (which is an unacceptable
  solution),  or
- manually clearing the app parse cache. see the answer for how to do
  that

This method must be called before you call Parse.initialize...

```
public static boolean deleteInstallationCache(Context context) {
        boolean deletedParseFolder = false;
        File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        File parseApp = new File(cacheDir.getParent(),"app_Parse");
        File installationId = new File(parseApp,"installationId");
        File currentInstallation = new File(parseApp,"currentInstallation");
        if(installationId.exists()) {
            deletedParseFolder = deletedParseFolder || installationId.delete();
        }
        if(currentInstallation.exists()) {
         deletedParseFolder = deletedParseFolder && currentInstallation.delete();
        }
        return deletedParseFolder;
    }
```

Comment: I called this function. The File variables all load correctly. It then enters the first if-statement and loads 'true' into deleteParseFolder. It skips the second if-statement. After doing this I call the code in my initial question with the added callback and I am still getting the "object not found for update" exception.

Comment: I have had a couple times when there is no exception, but the item still does not appear in the Installation database.

Comment: I did get the Parse Installation to go to the database after a full uninstall/reinstall of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use package-private method
ParseInstallation.clearCurrentInstallationFromDisk(Context context)

```
    public static void clearParseInstallation(Context context) {
        try {
            Method method = ParseInstallation.class.getDeclaredMethod("clearCurrentInstallationFromDisk", Context.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(null, context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method return exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: clearCurrentInstallationFromDisk [class android.content.Context]

Answer (score 1):

add "bolts-android-x.x.x" lib in libs folder.
You can find it in the Parse SDK zip file